# How to get a content of array file using PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am a new with PowerShell, I want to read a text file. But my text file format has a head. This is the format looks like

```
Name
(One Tab) Jhonny/Male
(One Enter)
(One Tab)  Merry/Female

Class
(One Tab)  XI/AB
(One Enter)
(One Tab)  XII/AB
```

I want to read the content each head, like Name or Class. If I read head Name, It will return

```
Jhonny/Male
Merry/Female
```

Anyone can give me idea, please? Thanks a lot

This is what I try. But it does not work

```
$File = Get-Content -Path .\Data.txt
$Name = $File.Name
Write-Output $Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following if we assume text under he headers are indented with white space:

```
$name = $false
switch -regex -file Data.txt {
    '^Name' { $name = $true; continue }
    '^\s' { if ($name) { $_.Trim() }}
    '^\S' { if ($name) { return }}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this can help. If you want to replace tab while printing you can do that with the replace command also in powershell.

```
$content=Get-Content -Path "E:\test.txt"
$contentHead="Name"
for($i=0 ; $i -lt $content.Count ; $i++){
    if($content[$i] -eq $contentHead){
        for($i=$i+1; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++){
            Write-Output $content[$i]
            if($content[$i][0] -ne "`t"){
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [do not use screenshots for code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Questions, answers, it's all the same - code in image is not searchable and offers little if any value.

Comment: Hi @Nitesh, Thank you for your answer. But I updated my question, It should be has an enter after (One Tab) Jhonny/Male. With your answer, I only get Jhonny/Male without Merry/Female because there is an enter. Need your help, please